# Generating coordinates for abstract triangulation

Tags: geometry, coordinates

I have a piece of abstract triangulation, made entirely out of equilateral triangles, that describes a curved 2d space. As such, some vertices have for example 7 equilateral triangles attached to them. Now I want to draw this as a terrain.

This has to be done in 3d, so I expect a lot of saddle nodes and some cone-like structures. I am currently trying to find a nice algorithm that does this for me, but as of yet I have come out empty handed. In principle you could 'just' solve a large set of quadratic equations that fixes all the distances, but this is unfeasible. I would be content with an algorithm that gives a best approximation.

Any advice?